# How do I restore geometry from the second page of a section or chapter?

Tags: geometry

My thesis template requires `2in` `top`, `1in` `left`, `1in` `right`, and `1in` `bottom` only on the page where a `section` begins. From the next page, I need to `restore` my default settings: `1in top`, `1in bottom`, `1in left`, and `1in right`. Using a `geometry` package, I defined default margins for the whole document. Right before the line where a Section begins, I defined `newgeometry` and it works good too. I write three paragraphs on the same page where the section starts. A part of my third paragraph belongs to the same page and remaining part should continue next page (where I need to restore the geometry). How do I do this?

If I put `\restoregeometry` right before the third section, the whole section goes to the next page which I don't like. If I put `\restoregeometry` in the middle of the third paragraph, it gives me a line break. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{5em}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=2in,bottom=1in} 
\section{First Section}
 Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section. Here is my first paragraph of this section.

Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. Here is my second paragraph of this section. 


Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page. Here is my third paragraph of this section. Part of this paragraph belongs to this page and some part goes to the next page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't change the geometry, simply add a space before the section.

Comment: Welcome! As @UlrikeFischer says, you want to change the definition of `\section` so that it inserts the relevant space. But why are you not using a class with chapters? Chapters automatically start a new page. If you need chapter-like section breaking, use chapters. You can configure the appearance etc. as you wish. Also, don't change the line spacing like that. Use `setspace` if you need it.

Comment: Your are using the wrong class for a thesis. For several reason, is  better some book-like class.  Said that, I would suggest  `\documentclass[article]{memoir}` if you really want to mimic the  article style in chapters of a thesis. Then `\newpage\vspace*{1in}\chapter{...}` is enough, or alternatively, redefine `\chapter`.